# Beta Constrained Markowitz Minimum Variance Portfolio - Closed Form Solution

Tags: optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, portfolio-optimization, beta

This question is related to recent rule changes in the [Quantopian Open](https://www.quantopian.com/posts/june-contest-rules-update-its-all-about-that-beta-star?utm_source=All+Active+Members&utm_campaign=34d911f0c5-15-05-20-May-monthly&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_7cca55778a-34d911f0c5-60434073).

I am trying to figure out a closed form solution to a beta constrained minimum variance portfolio problem but it doesn't seem particularly tractable. Has anyone else tried this? So far, I have set up the problem

$$\begin{align}
\min_w \quad& w^\prime \Sigma w \\
s.t. \quad& w^\prime\vec 1 = 1 \\
\text{and} \quad & w^\prime \beta = c
\end{align}$$

where

- $w$ is the vector of portfolio weights, our control
- $\Sigma$ is the total covariance matrix
- $\beta$ is the vector of CAPM-type market betas
- $c$ a constant that the portfolio beta should be equal to

Changing constraints to Lagrange multipliers the objective becomes

$$\min_w \quad w^\prime\Sigma w - \lambda_1(w^\prime\vec 1 - 1) - \lambda_2(w^\prime\beta - c)$$

the first order conditions are

$$\begin{align}
0 &= 2w^\prime\Sigma - \lambda_1\vec 1 - \lambda_2 \beta\\
1 &= w^\prime\vec 1\\
c &= w^\prime\beta
\end{align}$$

I cannot seem to get the equations to work out nicely, perhaps no closed form solution exists but I wanted to check here and see if anyone could get something reasonable before I go to numerical optimization.

Comment: The constraints can be grouped together to something like $Aw=b$, so that the lambdas are a vector. This set-up is actually pretty common. I typically refer to the derivation in http://edoc.hu-berlin.de/master/jiao-wei-2003-12-16/PDF/jiao.pdf

Comment: @John I like this reference but I would suggest pointing interested readers to page 7 (pdf page 15) when making it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $\Sigma$ is invertible, then
\begin{align}
2\omega' = \lambda_1\overrightarrow{1}'\Sigma^{-1}+\lambda_2\beta'\Sigma^{-1}.
\end{align}
We can then solve $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ from the system of equations
\begin{align*}
2 &= \lambda_1\overrightarrow{1}'\Sigma^{-1}\overrightarrow{1}+\lambda_2\beta'\Sigma^{-1}\overrightarrow{1}\\
2c &= \lambda_1\overrightarrow{1}'\Sigma^{-1}\beta+\lambda_2\beta'\Sigma^{-1}\beta.
\end{align*}
Consequently, $\omega$ can be obtained from the above equation.

Comment: I was hoping for some cute $w = \ldots$ reduced form type equation but this certainly answers the question. edit - I bet mathematica could help but I don't own it

Comment: @user25064, I believe this can be done in Excel 2010.

Comment: I was referring to symbolic manipulation...

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem. I don't think the problem is set up correctly quite yet. I rewrote it slightly to correspond to how it's generally written as a quadratic program.

The optimization problem you write down fixes betas to be a certain value. That could make sense but instead I wondered if we could simply minimize beta across the portfolio while minimizing correlations. In that case, the optimization problem becomes:

\begin{align}
\min_w \quad& w^\prime \Sigma w + w^\prime\lvert\beta\rvert\\
s.t. \quad& w^\prime\vec 1 = 1 \\
\text{and} \quad & w > 0
\end{align}

I don't think a closed-form solution exists to this problem. But it's quite easy (and fast) to solve this with a quadratic optimizer such as provided by `cvxopt`. Here is some example code:

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cvxopt as opt
from cvxopt import blas, solvers
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(123)

# Turn off progress printing 
solvers.options['show_progress'] = False

## NUMBER OF ASSETS
n_assets = 4

## NUMBER OF OBSERVATIONS
n_obs = 1000

# Generate returns
return_vec = np.random.randn(n_assets, n_obs)

betas = np.array([.1, .8, .2, .05])

def markowitz_beta(returns, betas):
    n = len(returns)
    returns = np.asmatrix(returns)

    # Convert to cvxopt matrices
    # minimize: w * mu*S * w + betas * x 
    S = opt.matrix(np.cov(returns))

    # Minimize betas, can add mean returns here if desired
    pbar = opt.matrix(np.abs(betas))

    # Create constraint matrices
    # Gx < h: Every item is positive
    G = opt.matrix(-np.eye(n))   # negative n x n identity matrix
    h = opt.matrix(np.zeros(n))
    # Ax = b sum of all items = 1
    A = opt.matrix(1.0, (1, n))
    b = opt.matrix(1.0)

    # CALCULATE THE OPTIMAL PORTFOLIO
    wt = solvers.qp(S, pbar, G, h, A, b)['x']
    return np.asarray(wt).ravel()

weights = markowitz_beta(return_vec, betas)
print weights
print betas.ravel()
print np.dot(weights, betas)


Output:

[  3.50677883e-01   3.34638307e-07   2.50326847e-01   3.98994936e-01]
[ 0.1   0.8   0.2   0.05]
0.105083172131

As you can see, the highest betas receive very low weights.

We also wrote a blog post on this (and the code is a version from there) which you can find here: https://www.quantopian.com/posts/the-efficient-frontier-markowitz-portfolio-optimization-using-cvxopt-repost-cloning-of-nb-now-enabled

Disclaimer: I work at Quantopian.

Comment: You just wrote down a different problem which is totally fine. The problem I was trying to solve has a closed form solution because my constraint is an equality constraint (I happen to use $c=0$) and I allow long/short portfolios. Still interesting and illustrative, thanks

Comment: Ah, you're probably right in that case. I wonder in which cases you would want to target a specific beta value for your portfolio though.

Comment: Separately, I posted this NB on our forums: https://www.quantopian.com/posts/beta-constrained-markowitz-minimum-variance-portfolio